# Running ElasticSearch with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch, import, pom.xml

I'm trying to follow a tutorial (http://www.lindstromhenrik.com/debugging-elasticsearch-in-eclipse/) about importing ElasticSearch into Eclipse in order to practice debugging it, but whenever I download ElasticSearch (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tags), there is no pom.xml file which the article references. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the maven repository of elasticsearch :

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch

You should find the version of ES you're working on, and then by clicking on it you will be able to find the pom.xml file on the "Files" line.

The github repository gives you the complete gradle configuration of the project, which you can easily run with an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

The article you are following is from `2012-08-22`. A lot has changed in Elasticsearch in the last 5 years, and it no longer uses maven as a build system.

To build elasticsearch you will need [gradle](http://gradle.org/).

The elasticsearch repository has a CONTRIBUTING document that explains [how to import the project](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-the-elasticsearch-codebase) into your IDE of choice.